# Downloading OS X Lion after the release of Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

I bought OS X Lion through the App Store long ago and installed it to my Mac Mini (Early 2011) which came with Snow Leopard bundled.

The Mac Mini was having some issues so I decided to format and reinstall using the Recovery Partition created by Lion. However, the process of downloading installation files was getting stuck and the installation did not advance, so I decided to install Snow Leopard instead and make the upgrade to OS X Lion from the App Store, like I did originally.

Sadly, I find that there's currently no way of downloading OS X Lion from Apple's site. What can I do? How can I get a hold of a product I paid for?

The Apple site prompts me to buy and install Mountain Lion which I don't want.

Comment: So are you on Snow Leopard right now? Does your App Store application have a "Purchases" tab like the current one?

Comment: Apparently, the problem was that I was under an old version of 10.6 and I couldn't see the App Store. I have updated to the latest Snow Leopard version and was able to redownload from the Purchases tab. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download apps you've purchased before (including OS X installers) from the Mac App Store application. Sign in and switch to the purchases tab:

[image]

All of your previous purchases should appear, including the Lion installer:

[image]

If you don't have the App Store, make sure you've updated to at least 10.6.6.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried unhiding OS X Lion in App store? You do that by following this: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4928 ?

I had to do that one time when one of my apps dissappeared.